# I want to use Python to test the device's Bluetooth rssi value, but there is a problem when installing it in Ubuntu

Tags: python, bluetooth, pybluez

After I use `sudo apt-get install bluetooth libbluetooth-dev` (libbluetooth-dev and bluetooth are the latest version) ，I type `sudo python3 -m pip install pybluez`, but it shows:

```
Collecting pybluez
  Using cached PyBluez-0.23.tar.gz (97 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in PyBluez setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Please, who can help me solve this

Answer (score 4):

The pypi version is outdated and this issue is fixed in the dev version ages ago. Please install it from source with below command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez.git#egg=pybluez
```

This has already been discussed in this [github issue](https://github.com/pybluez/pybluez/issues/431)

Comment: Thank you for your replying, I try it:                                                                           
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting setuptools==57.5.0
  Using cached setuptools-57.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (819 kB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-57.5.0                                                                                                    
however, pybluez still cannot be installed...